# Send to remote MSMQ silently fails

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

I'm trying to send a message to a remote message queue in C#.

This is the path I'm using:

```
FormatName:Direct=TCP:192.168.0.10\private$\test_in
```

The .Send method is passed without exception but no message appears in the remote queue. Oddly, I can receive from the same queue without problems.

The queue on the remote machine is non-transactional, as is the code on my local machine. It also has 'Full Access' to 'Everyone'.

I've read up a few responses to people having similar problems, but none of the solutions seem to apply to me. I've checked the Outgoing Queues section on my local machine, and they all show as 'Connected' to the remote queue, but also indicate that no messages have been sent. It looks like it hasn't even tried.

Any ideas what my issue might be? Thanks.

EDIT: A bit more information - the local machine is Windows 8. The remote machine is Windows Server 2012.

EDIT: hugh's answer led me to the actual cause. I needed to add permissions for ANONYMOUS LOGON to the remote queue ('Everyone' wasn't sufficient). Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that an outgoing queue has been created on the sending machine, and this queue has no messages, means that the message has been transmitted to the receiving machine.

So the problem will be something on the receiving machine. Probably queue permissions. Are the machines in different windows domains?

If you enable the msmq event log (Event Viewer -> Apps and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> MSMQ) you should be able to see exactly what happens after the message arrives.

Comment: I was getting 'Message Received Over Network' messages, but nothing else. Thankfully this led me to search for that message and I found the actual cause, so thanks for the clue!

Comment: I meant to add about anonynous logon, hence me asking about different domains. Damn

Comment: How enable the msmq event log ?

Comment: @Kiquenet After opening the log there is an "enable" button on the right hand side I think.

Comment: For me nothing is showing in remote log as well. In local log it shows message sent

Answer (score 5):

hugh's answer led me to the actual cause. I needed to add permissions for ANONYMOUS LOGON to the remote queue ('Everyone' wasn't sufficient). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Anonymous Logon wasn't the fix in my situation, but giving "Everyone" Full Control was the trick!

Comment: @BrienFoss that is because your sender was on the same AD domain as your receiver.

Comment: So how does one actually conclude that this is what's happening, without just trying 100 different things until it works? Is there no log where you can see what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, the messages were not showing up in the remote private queue either. I took a look at one of the answers here and gave 'Everyone' full-control to the private queue, and then messages started to populate the queue.
However with a little refinement, I determined that 'Everyone' wasn't appropriate for my situation.
My goal was to have a production server write messages to a development server. So in the end what I needed to do was add the server/workstation name to this security list with 'Send' permissions only.

Click the Add button, and find your server/workstation name in the list of Active Directory computer object types.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of your format string:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:YOURMACHINENAME\private$\YourQueueName
```

Please note that the first part `FormatName:DIRECT` may be case-sensitive. I have not used it with `TCP` yet, but I guess case-sensitivity applies regardless off the used protocol.

You might already know the MSDN page for the [Direct Format Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but if not, it might as well be worth a read.